# Instantiating shapes using the Factory Design Pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-method

Trying to learn  the factory design pattern, came up with some code based on a Shape Factory (found this example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)). Is this the right way to implement the factory pattern?

```
interface Shape{
    void draw();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(" Drawing A Rectangle!");

    }

}

class Circle implements Shape{

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(" Drawing A cIRCLE!");

    }

}


class Triangle implements Shape{

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(" Drawing A Triangle!");

    }

}


class ShapeFactory{


    public static Shape getShape(String shapeType)
    {
        Shape shape = null;
        switch(shapeType.toUpperCase()){

        case "CIRCLE":
        shape = new Circle();
        break;

        case "RECTANGLE":
            shape = new Rectangle();
            break;

         case "TRIANGLE":
            shape = new Triangle();
            break;
        }

            return shape;
    }


}

public class FactoryExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = ShapeFactory.getShape("rectangle");
         s.draw();
         s = ShapeFactory.getShape("triangle");
        s.draw();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using constants to be passed to the factory for creation. This prevents typos from being introduced, e.g. `ShapeFactory.createShape(Shape.TRIANGLE);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rewrite **`getShape`** as follows:

```
public static Shape getShape(String shapeType) {
    switch (shapeType.trim().toUpperCase()) {
        case "CIRCLE":
            return new Circle();

        case "RECTANGLE":
            return new Rectangle();

        case "TRIANGLE":
            return new Triangle();

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Naming the method `getShape(…)` suggests that it's going to retrieve the same cached instance with every call.  A more appropriate name to convey what the method does would be `makeShape(…)`, or maybe `newShape(…)`.  (Unfortunately, you followed a bad example.)